# How might I join two unrelated Django models via distance?

Tags: python, django, geospatial, django-queryset, geodjango

I'm working on a Django project that requires me to report, via web service, for each item in the School table all Hospitals that just so happen to be a set distance away. Here is a dummy implementation of the two models:

```
class School(models.Model):
    location = models.PointField(srid=4326, geography=True)
    ...some other fields...
    objects = models.GeoManager()

class Hospital
    location = models.PointField(srid=4326, geography=True)
    ...some other fields...
    objects = models.GeoManager()
```

I will state for the record that this is a contrived example, but the point remains that:

1. Neither model has a foreign key relationship with the other (nor should they)
2. The only relationship is via distance

Now, I am using Django Rest Framework (DRF) to render my requests, and I am using the Serializer classes that it provides to do something along these lines:

```
class SchoolSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    nearby_hospitals = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_nearby_hospitals')

    class Meta:
        model = School
        fields = ('location', 'nearby_hospitals',)

    def get_nearby_hospitals(self, obj):

        geom = obj.location

        try:

            locations = Hospitals.objects.filter(loc__dwithin=(geom, 10000))
            return HospitalSerializer(locations, many=True).data
        except:
            return
```

This *works* but it is not *efficient*. In essence what happens is that DRF loads all Schools, and then from there loops over each school and runs the query in get_nearby_hospitals. The number of database queries is equal to the number of items in Schools plus one (to get the Schools).

Ideally I'd like a Django solution that performs something along these lines (obviously with the fields listed out, aliases for clashing ID column names, etc):

```
SELECT * FROM schools JOIN 
hospitals ON ST_DWithin(schools.location, hospitals.location, 10000)
```

The above query produces the intersection of all Schools and Hospitals within the proper distance. I could merge these results in manually with the `School.objects.all()` queryset or write a better query and call the `raw` QuerySet method to get what I'm after in one shot.

Is there a better or more 'Django Way' solution to this problem?

Comment: How did you count the number of queries? What is the Django Rest Framewok view you are using?

Comment: I counted the number of queries using Django Debug Toolbar. The view in question is a DRF ListCreateAPIView.

Comment: Make sure you test the json version of the page, not the HTML. In fact, building the form for the Create API view in HTML could result in a bunch of queries that are usually not needed.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using GraphQL/DataLoaders to solve this N+1 problem as DRF is not well suited for it. However, this can be done in DRF by using a custom ListSerializer (django creates one for you behind the scenes automatically) and overloading the to_representation functions of both List/Child serializers:

```
class SchoolListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    def to_representation(self, data):
        iterable = data.all() if isinstance(data, models.Manager) else data
        keys = [(item.id, item.location) for item in iterable]
        # perform your bulk nearby query here using the id/locations
        # the result should be a dict with school id keys and list of serialized hospital values
        # {1: [hospital.to_dict(), hospital.to_dict(), ...], ...}
        nearby_by_id = ...
        extra = {
            'nearby_hospitals_by_id': nearby_by_id
        }
        return [
            self.child.to_representation(item, **extra) for item in iterable
        ]

class SchoolSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = School
        fields = ('location', )
        list_serializer_class = SchoolListSerializer

    def to_representation(self, instance, **extra):
        response = super().to_representation(instance)
        response['nearby_hospitals'] = extra['nearby_hospitals_by_id'][instance.id]
        return response
```

I left out the actual DB query, however the example will work with any queries regardless of where the data resides.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure it's better, but I think you are taking the problem in the reverse direction. I see no reason for any JOIN at all.

```
class SchoolSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    nearby_hospitals = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_nearby_hospitals')

    class Meta:
        model = School
        fields = ('location', 'nearby_hospitals',)

    def get_nearby_hospitals(self, obj):

        geom = obj.location

        try:
            # why do you query School model if you want nearby hospitals?
            locations = Hospital.objects.filter(location__distance_lte=(geom ,10000))
            return locations # not sure it's the good type to return though
        except:
            return
```

Comment: It's because it's a typo in my example. The line under the "try" block is supposed to be Hospital, as you said. However, it doesn't solve the core problem here.